# jquery select THIS id inside li

Tags: jquery

How to use "THIS" in the right way in order to select an ID inside "li"?

```
<li class="item">
    <div id="sale_container">text</div>
</li>

$("li.item").hover(function () {
        $("#sale_container").fadeIn(400);
    })
    $("li.item").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#sale_container").fadeOut(400);
    })
```

How ever it affects all li with class "item". So, i want it to take affect inside each li, when mouse is over.

This example doesn't work

```
$("li.item").hover(function () {
    $(this)("#sale_container").fadeIn(400);
})
$("li.item").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this)("#sale_container").fadeOut(400);
})
```

Comment: You can't have multiple tags with the same ID, also this can be done with pure CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250619/fade-in-out-with-css3

Comment: I think there will be aproblem in IE. How ever this looks nice

Comment: Change the id to a class, and the selector from @David's answer to `$(this).find(".sale_container").fadeIn(400);` and you'll have 0 issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since IDs are unique, you only need to use `$('#sale_container')` without any other qualifiers.

Assume you are not using an ID, then you'd use:

`$(this).find(...).fadeIn(400);` "..." being a selector of what you're looking for inside, which could be `("div")` or a `(".myClassname")` etc.

Comment: I never said it wasn't bad practice... just that no were in the specs does it mention id's are unique... I think 100% of browsers support non unique id's and Ive seen some very well written sites use non uniques id...

Comment: Of course those sites were smart enough to NEVER try to grab the element by id from the global scope... always a more local one where the id WAS unique... I dont i was just sayin...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$(this)("#sale_container").fadeIn(400);
```

With:

```
$(this).find("#sale_container").fadeIn(400);
```

Or even:

```
$(this).children().fadeIn(400); // will fade any element inside .item
```

Note that you can only have one unique ID on one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$("li.item").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("#sale_container").fadeIn(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the find function to find an element contained inside the parent element (this).

```
$("li.item").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("#sale_container").fadeIn(400);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("li.item").hover(function () {
        $("#sale_container",$(this)).fadeIn(400);
    }, function () {
       $("#sale_container",$(this)).fadeOut(400);
    });
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dubeynee/GNTMT/)

Comment: `$(this)` isnt needed, just `this` would do :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.Can you explain difference between `this` and `$(this)`